# Excluding set of words in html code keyword search

Tags: html, python-2.7, search, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm working on a program that creates tags for HTML codes. The program works like this:

1. A random sample URL is selected
2. With BeautifulSoup, it crawls to find all related URLs connected to the sample URL
3. Convert all HTML codes of URLs found in point No. 2 into text using `requests.get(url).text`
4. Perform text search for set of predefined keywords
5. Mark as 1 if a particular keyword is found and 0 if not found

My problem is, when performing search on HTML code that is already converted to text, I cannot exclude any section containing `"src = http://...."` as it varies in different websites. That makes some keywords become irrelevant.

Is there any way to exclude any words starting with `"src"` in such cases? Or is there any other keyword search method to overcome this?

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is with step n°2 since you are trying to convert the HTML to **text** and [requests.get(url).text](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/?highlight=header#requests.Response.text) return the HTML of the response.

```
>>> import requests
>>> r = requests.get("http://example.com")
>>> r.text
u'<!doctype html>\n<html>\n<head>\n ..........'
```

You could use [get_text](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text) in `BeautifulSoup` to extract the text.

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> s = BeautifulSoup(r.text)
>>>s.get_text().replace("\n","")
u'Example Domain ....."
```

Comment: Thanks for giving some ideas. I'm new in programming, a little bit lost when you said u'Example Domain .....". Is that where I put those keywords? how about when I have list of keywords, saved in an array. Kindly advise, thanks